# Simulating a scale, balancing weight from lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have simulated balancing a scale by having each side total the same weight.

The scale has two weights (left and right side) and some spare weights:

```
weights = [3, 4]
spare_weights = [1, 2, 7, 7]
```

A maximum of two weights can be used from the spare weights to balance the scale. The spare(s) may be on a single side or split between both.

The output should be the minimum number of weight needed to balance the scale.

```
import itertools

weights = [3, 4]
spare_weights = [1, 2, 7, 7]
c = enumerate([subset for l in range(0, 3) for subset in itertools.combinations(spare_weights, l)])

cc = cc = list(itertools.combinations(c, 2))

left, right = weights
qualifying_combos = []
for c in cc:
    l, r = c
    if sum(l[1]) + left == sum(r[1]) + right:
        qualifying_combos.append(list(l[1]) + list(r[1]))
    elif sum(l[1]) + right == sum(r[1]) + left:
        qualifying_combos.append(list(l[1]) + list(r[1]))
print(min(qualifying_combos, key=len))
```

output:

```
[1]
```

Is there a more elegant way to code this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Write functions. Make this a `balance_scale` function, that returns the minimum.
2. Your variable names are pretty poor, single letter variable names leave people guessing at what they mean.
3. You should change `cc = cc = ...` to just one assignment.

---

Since you can use a maximum of two spare weights the solution can be a lot simpler than you've produced.

1. \$W_1\$ is the smaller weight in `weights` and \$W_2\$ is the larger.
2. If \$W_1 = W_2\$ then you return an empty list.
3. We can determine what weight is needed when only one weight can be used.

   \$S = W_2 - W_1\$

   Therefore if \$S\$ is in `spare_weights` then we can return \$S\$.
4. For each \$S_1\$ in `spare_weights` we can determine the weight needed, \$S_2\$.

   \$S_2 = |W_2 - W_1 - S_1|\$

   We take the absolute as this weight can be on either side of the scale. If the non-absolute value of \$S_2\$ is positive then we add it to \$W_1 + S_1\$ if it's negative then we add it to \$W_2\$.

If we add \$0\$ twice to `spare_weights`, then we can see that (4), (3) and (2) are all roughly the same equation.

We don't need to check if \$S_1\$ and \$S_2\$ both exist in `spare_weights`, as the only time they are the same is if \$W_1 = W_2\$, and so they would both be 0. We however have to assign \$S_1\$ to 0 first.

```
def balance_scale(scale, spares):
    w1, w2 = sorted(scale)
    spare_set = set(spares) | {0}
    for s1 in [0] + spares:
        s2 = abs(w2 - w1 - s1)
        if s2 in spare_set:
            return [i for i in [s1, s2] if i]
    return None


print(balance_scale([4, 3], [1, 2, 7, 7]))
```

```
[1]
```